# High Volume Settings for Apache / Tomcat/ Mod.JK

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have a 3.5 GB 2 CPU server running on tomcat/apache with mod.jk.  We are seeing our server itself having plenty of memory available and tomcat is not showing anything crazy in terms of GC.

We have been trying different settings for the maxClients maxThreads and the socket_timeout in workers.properties.

we are averaging around 4000 concurrent users, its a bit hard to estimate number of requests per second but its probably 400 i would say (just a guess).

Should the maxThreads in tomcat always be greater than maxClients in httpd? and if so by how much.

We tried maxClients at 250 and maxThreads at 300 and we were seeing slowness form the web but the server looked fine.

Also our average httpd size is 10mg.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: this might be better to go on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comprehensive blog post about to set `maxClients` and `maxThreads` properties correctly. In short `maxClients` should be >= `maxThreads`

http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/maxclients-in-apache-and-its-effect-on-tomcat-during-full-gc/

Comment: maybe i'm confused.. i read that and it was more on maxClients for apache.  I would assume based on that diagram that you do not want to send more requests to apache then threads.. and thats why maxClients would be less than maxThreads